# DisplayPort Chip Identification

Tags: identification

What is this chip?
[image: Image of PCB w/ chip circled]

Found on the [Numato Opsis](https://opsis.hdmi2usb.tv/) fpga graphics board.

Comment: You've partly obscured the designator, but it looks like "D11", implying some kind of diode.

Answer (score 2):

If you zoom in on the image you will see that the element you circled is marked as D11.  The sister element on the other DisplayPort is marked as D3.

If you go to the link you supplied you can download the schematics for the board.  Searching those for D11 takes you to page 6 where you can see that D11 is a diode that is used for reverse power protection of the board from a badly wired display port cable.  D3 provides the same function for the other port.

I can't see where the actual part numbers are specified, but given the wealth of information on that site I am sure they are there somewhere.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DisplayPort transceivers are part of the FPGA itself, you have to instantiate the respective IP cores in order to be able to use those DisplayPort connectors.